# Adding a SOAP Header from a string to a request built from WSDL

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm connecting to a WSDL through visual studio to build a web request in c#, but having an issue with authentication. The company we're working with requires information to be in the header, but doesn't expose the information they need through the WSDL, saying that, "this exact header needs to be included in all requests".

Theoretically I'd like to just get the header built in a StringBuilder object and attached to the client object, but I can't see how to do that easily. Everything I use, like WCFExtras+ or even just System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeader wants an object, values, and a ns (which is obvious with C# being an OOPL).

I tried doing something like this, but i realized you can't just add XML manually like this, it strips out < and > into web-safe text equivalents:

```
using (var client = new productsClient())
{
    using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
    {
        MessageHeader<string> header = new MessageHeader<string>("wsse:Security", true, "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", true);
        var untyped = header.GetUntypedHeader(hardcodedHeader, "http://api.xxxcon.com/xxx");
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(untyped);

        var request = new productRequest();
        response = client.getProduct(request);
    }
}
```

Perhaps using the MessageHeader.CreateHeader is the answer? I can use this to create a simple header that has one line 
(in the shape of value) but when i try to nest the requests together to create a parent and child relationship:

```
var username = System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeader.CreateHeader
("wsse:UsernameToken ", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
, usernameString);

var pw = System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeader.CreateHeader
("wsse:Password", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
, passwordString);

var header1 = System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeader.CreateHeader
("wsse:UsernameToken ", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
, "", username);
```

But again, this throws an error. I suspect this class wasn't meant to nest xml objects like this.

All in all, I'd like to actually use the WSDL and not have to manually generate all the XML, but it seems i'm hindered by object-orientation, when i really want to just say, "here's the header, just trust me that everything is there. slap this baby right on".

Is anybody familiar with what to do in this circumstance? Thank you in advance.